# JAVA - Not allowing jump button holding

Tags: java

My code:

```
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    tempObject.setJumping(true);
    tempObject.setVelY(-10);
}
```

In this code, when I press the SPACE key, the player jumps, clearly. Except that is not where it ends, or else I would not be doing this. When I hold the SPACE bar, the player flies. I tried a timer, but it will not allow rapid jumping, which will be needed for a platformer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if `jumping` is `true`?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a `JumpingState` enum:

```
enum JumpingState {NOT_JUMPING, JUMPING}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && jumpingState == JumpingState.NOT_JUMPING) {
   jumpingState = JumpingState.JUMPING;
   tempObject.setJumping(true);
   // Start timer here to revert tempObject and set jumpingState back to NOT_JUMPING
}
```

in conjunction with a timer that can be used to control when the player is currently jumping. Any jump event that comes in while the player is currently jumping can simply be ignored based on checking `JumpingState`.

Comment: When I use the jumpingState == JumpingState.NOT_JUMPING, I get an error under jumpingState.

Comment: Yeah, the above code is just a rough example to point you in the right direction. I'll leave it to you to fix any errors.

Comment: Also, since you're using a timer that means you have 2 threads so the jumpingState variable needs to be thread safe...volatile keyword or use of the synchronize keyword as needed to protect any state accessed by both the UI thread and timer thread

Comment: Hmm this is very hard for me. I am just a beginner. I got far enough to make the jump only happen once. After that one jump, the player will not jump any longer.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose your issue without seeing more code. My advice would be to use a debugger and walk through the code to check your assumptions. Keep at it and you'll get there.